Pushing an empty soda can against a large rock (and the inverse situation)
Why is it that when I push an empty soda can against a large rock, the can gets dented quite a bit, but when I push the large rock against the empty soda can, it just gets accelerated along with the rock and gets very little dented?
The acceleration of the system should be the same. For me, this situation is very counter-intuitive (that the order matters). I think it has to do with Newton's third law, am I right about this? What more? Materials resistance? Sorry about my English, it's not my native language.

Hello! Can you explain why you this is counter intuitive for you? I feel like you can answer your own question if you clearly state your reasoning.

Hi! I think I may be confusing "contact forces" that lead to compression throughout the body structure, with forces like gravity, that are applied at all points (atoms?) of the body at the same time. I dunno.

I could well have asked it with a spring instead of an empty can... I'll sleep a little and then think more about this question. Thanks.

Call $F$ to the force that you make. $F$ is the same in both cases because the acceleration of the entire system is the same. Now think of the contact force between the can and the rock, call it $N$. Also, imagine that the mass of the can is very small relative to that of the rock.
In the first case, $N$ is about the same as $F$, because this force is the one that accelerates the rock (the force that you make on the can does not act on the rock, it acts on the can. Also, if instead of your hand you used a rock, which is not soft, that side would also be dented).
In the second case $N$ is negligible, because it is the force that the rock makes to accelerate the can. In this case $F$ acts on the rock, and it is the force responsible for accelerating it.

Ahhhhh! It has a simple explanation after all. Thank you! I think I understand it better now. I'll sleep now and then think again about the question with your explanation in mind. I have a lot of difficulty with Newton's laws since the time I was in school (long time ago) but there are many everyday situations that they can explain!!
